# Make Datatables Retain page After Update And Run An External Function When The Table Refreshes

Tags: jquery, datatables

So this function retains the page after a server side update:

```
table.ajax.reload( null, false );
```

While this function allows you to run a callback after a server side update:

```
table.ajax.reload( function ( json ) {
    $('#myInput').val( json.lastInput );
} );
```

But I'm trying to do both right now. So I've tried this:

```
table.ajax.reload( null, false, function ( json ) {
        $('#myInput').val( json.lastInput );
 } );
```

It retains my `datatable` page but my callback doesn't even run a simple `alert` function. Is there any solution to this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Datatables API [table.ajax.reload(](https://datatables.net/reference/api/ajax.reload())) only support two (2) parameter.

You can code it like this:

```
table.ajax.reload( function (result){ /* your code here */}, false );
```

So your example can be like this:

```
table.ajax.reload( function ( json ) {
        $('#myInput').val( json.lastInput );
}, false );
```